# Apply templates based on Input Parameter

Tags: xslt

I am in need to apply templates according to the Input parameter given.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <section1>
        <math><mtext>This is section1 mtext</mtext></math>
    </section1>
    <section2>
        <math><mtext>This is section2 mtext</mtext></math>
    </section2>
</chapter>
```

If the user gives a Xpath expression as input parameter, then that particular Xpath should be selected and templates should be applied.

for example, if the user gives, "/chapter/section1/" as input parameter then required output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><chapter>
<section1>
<math>~rom1~This is section1 mtext</math>
</section1>
<section2>
<math>~rom~this is section2 mtext</math>
</section2>
</chapter>
```

if the user gives, "/chapter/section1/" and "/chapter/section2" as two input parameters then, the output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><chapter>
<section1>
<math>~rom1~This is section1 mtext</math>
</section1>
<section2>
<math>~rom2~this is section2 mtext</math>
</section2>
</chapter>
```

if the user does not give any parameters, then the output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><chapter>
<section1>
<math>~rom~This is section1 mtext</math>
</section1>
<section2>
<math>~rom~this is section2 mtext</math>
</section2>
</chapter>
```

I tried the below XSLT

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<xsl:param name="Xpath1"/>
<xsl:param name="Xpath2"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Xpath1//mtext"><xsl:text>~rom1~</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Xpath2//mtext"><xsl:text>~rom2~</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="m:mtext"><xsl:text>~rom~</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**If this is way is not possible kindly suggest an alternative to achieve this**

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?  Dynamic evaluation of strings as XPath expressions isn't something that pure XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 supports, but there is support in the current XSLT 3.0 draft if you're using Saxon, or processor-specific extensions otherwise.

Comment: @Ian Roberts: Thanks for quick reply. I am using Saxon processor. I could able to use XSLT 2.0. Is this achieved by some other way

Comment: Do you need to have a xpath expression as parameter or would be the node name enough (e.g section1 )?

Comment: @hr_117:I am in need to have a Xpath expression as parameter

Comment: Which version of Saxon 9 do you use? The commercial ones support http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/evaluate.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks for your reply. I use Saxon9he. When I use the below coding in my XSLT shows error `<xsl:template match="saxon:evaluate($Xpath1)/math/mtext)"><xsl:text>~rom1~</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`. Please note that I also added namespace xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" at the top. Kindly suggest how to use this funtion in `<xsl:template>`

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I am using the below version of Saxon:saxonhe9-2-1-2j

Comment: As far as I know, the extension functions are not available in the open source HE of Saxon, you need Saxon PE or EE.